# nodejs linkedin login passport nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

We had working **Node.js** code for **LinkedIn** social login.
With this latest updates we can't solve this code to work and this is our current **Node.js** code:

In previous code we had using like `r_liteprofile` and `r_emailaddress` and this was successfully worked. Now we created new app before a couple of days and we can't solve this problem.

Is there any help to solve this? Current error is: “message”:“failed to fetch user profile”

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udtly.png)

I have expected that changing names of scope will work, as previous code worked successfully on old API v1 with scopes `r_emailaddress` and `r_liteprofile`..

```
passport.use(
    new linkedinStrategy(
      {
        clientID: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: 'http://localhost:5000/server/api/users/linkedin/callback',
        scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'email']
      },
      async (accessToken, refreshToken, done) => {
        try {
          const userInfo = await linkedin.getProfile(
            process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
            process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET,
            accessToken
          );

      console.log(userInfo)
      
      let existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: userInfo.email });

      if (existingUser) {
        return done(null, existingUser);
      }

      const newUser = new User({
        name: userInfo.name,
        email: userInfo.email,
        accessToken: accessToken,
        refreshToken: refreshToken,
        type: 'linkedin'
      });

      await newUser.save();

      done(null, newUser);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      done(err, false);
    }
  }
)
```

);`

Comment: having same issue, any advancement?